# How to find the NOT of Data Table

Tags: c#, .net

I have two DataTables e.g., **dt1** and **dt2.** 
dt1 contains the list of all the countries and dt2 contains few countries list.
I need a datatable **dt3** which should contain all countries except the list of countries in **dt2**.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  SO will help you; we won't do your work for you.

Comment: Not a home work DonCallisto.
Actually i have a drop down list which contains certains values.
User can select values from it. I want to maintain two datatables.
One which is loaded from DB. and one temporary datatables which will contains values selected from dropdownlist
I want on ajax to rebind the datatables showing all values not contianing in present in the temporary dataTable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Enumerable.Except(IEnumerable, IEnumerable) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx):

```
DataTable onlyInFirstTable = dt1.AsEnumerable().Except(dt2.AsEnumerable()).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Great that is what was required.

Answer (score 3):

To use `Except`, you need to use the overload that takes an `IEqualityComparer<DataRow>` since the default comparer will return all rows in `dt1` since they are not the same `DataRow`s in `dt2`.

For example, using this simplistic implementation (you should add error handling):

```
public class CountryRowComparer : IEqualityComparer<DataRow>
{
    public bool Equals(DataRow r1, DataRow r2)
    {
        return r1["Country"] == r2["Country"];
    }

    public int GetHashCode(DataRow r)
    {       
        return r["Country"].GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

you can get the Countries in `dt1` that are not in `dt2` as follows:

```
var dt3 = dt1.AsEnumerable().Except(dt2.AsEnumerable(), new CountryRowComparer()).CopyToDataTable();
```

If you don't want to bother with creating an `IEqualityComparer` class just for this, another way to get the countries in `dt1` that are not in `dt2` would be:

```
var exclude = dt2.AsEnumerable()
                 .Select(r => r.Field<string>("Country"));

var dt3 = dt1.AsEnumerable()
             .Where(r => !exclude.Contains(r.Field<string>("Country")))
             .CopyToDataTable();
```